# 1c-bitrix как подключить javascript файл к сайте после установки модуля

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс, 1с, framework

1c-bitrix как подключить javascript файл к сайте после установки модуля

Answer (score 0):

$_asset->addJs(Cutil::GetAdditionalFileURL(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/yourfilename.js"));
Добавьте в хедер вашего шаблона.